# Error compiling static library c++ for tensorflow when gpu enabled in cmake

Tags: c++, tensorflow, cmake

I have compiled tensorflow in windows with visual studio 15 only CPU and it generated the static library correctly. However, I am having trouble compiling when the GPU is enabled. Visual studio raise the error: `C1060 not enough memory`

Has someone been able to generate the static library for c++?, it would be great if someone could help with this issue.

**Note:** The card graphic is GTX 1080 Ti (compute capability 61), so I don´t think this is the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the native 64 bit compiler? The 32>64 crosscompiler is of course limited to 4GB.

Comment: Yes, I am using 64 bit compiler. I tried in two ifferent machines and I still have the same issue, howevers it works fine only with CPU.

Comment: What do you mean, "the" 64 bit compiler? Host 64 or target 64?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, compiler in Visual Studio 2017 often produces such errors. To solve it you need to break some big array into the set of smaller ones. Also you can use older Visual Studio version.

Comment: Thanks for the help provided.

The project (tensorflow c++) I am using is quite large and complicated, so it could take time to find them. Could you tell me please if there is another way to fix this issue in visual studio 2015 (the project is olny compatible with this version)? Otherwise, I could try your solution.

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You can try to play with project settings in C/C++ -> Optimization

Comment: Ok, Thank you I will try that. Regards.